# Install Laravel on simple server without commandline

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, composer-php, web-hosting

I have a webhost called e.g. `http://www.example.com`. When I use FTP to put my files in there, I can only acces the `public_html` folder. In that folder I want to use `Laravel`.

Is this possible? Because there is no `terminal` and I can't use `ssh`.
So installing composer isn't an option I think.

Thanks,

Comment: http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download to your local machine, install it, and then upload to a web server. That's what I do in shared hosting solutions if they don't give me terminal access.

Comment: Okey, so you don't need to run the composer/artisan command in your server

Comment: Exactly! Just make sure server requirements are sufficient (PHP version, mcrypt extension etc.)

Comment: I have copied all the files into the public_html on my server. but when I surf to my site: http://www.example.com/public I get this error: `{"error": "File not found"}`

Comment: Have you removed public segment from your app? http://creolab.hr/2013/03/removing-the-public-segment-in-a-laravel-4-app/

Comment: what about adding controllers? normally you have to do `php composer dump autoload`

Comment: @Ash then dump first, upload later :)

Comment: @Arda - yes, but without access to commandline, if you want to add controllers you can't because no access to composer...

Comment: @Ash do you mean to create new controllers by command line (like `php artisan controller:make StuffController` )? You can simply create them manually. It's the handicap that you can't use artisan commands with such servers. If else, sorry I didn't get your point. 

Also there are ways to call controllers



And there's even a Web artisan package for L4:
http://lukaswhite.com/blog/post/2014/running-laravel-artisan-commands-your-admin-dashboard-gui/

https://github.com/JN-Jones/web-artisan

Comment: How would you configure the web server to point to the public/index.php file of Laravel without terminal access?

Comment: @Yoga you need to either change your public folder to something like public_html depending your hosting provider, or remove that altogether (which is not suggested). Oh and I don't suggest using a shared hosting (with cpanel etc.) for Laravel in 2019 because such limitations.